# Rails console hanging in dokku droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, digital-ocean, dokku

I just moved from heroku to a digital ocean dokku one-klick droplet and it's working fine exept of the rails console. Since I thought it might be a problem with missing ram I upgraded my droplet to 2gb but it still won't work... 
Everytime I run "dokku run  rails c", the console is loading in the right enviromnent and it seems to be fine. But when I type in something (2+2 or User.all,...) and hit enter, there is no processing of the console. It's just hanging and the only thing I can do is to quit the console (ctrl+c). No errors are displayed...

I already reinstalled the app completely but it didn't help. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After having the same issue with a fresh installation of dokku on a virtual machine I solved this problem with updating dokku ... 
https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/getting-started/upgrading.md

Comment: I had the same issue with version 0.19.2.  Upgrading to version 0.19.10 fixed it for me.